# Necesito marcar más de una checkbox, pero el código me da error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, checkbox

Esta es una modificación para marcar más de una categoría personalizada en wordpress.

Me gustaría poder marcar más de una opción con la casilla de verificación, el fragmento que me permite hacerlo es comentado. El problema es que si descomente el código toda la web cae.

La clase de walker, lo que hace es permitirme cambiar el formato por radio.

```
function wpse_woothemes_sensei_term_radio_checklist( $args ) {

if ( ! empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) && ( $args['taxonomy'] === 'lesson-category' || $args['taxonomy'] === 'course-category' ) /* <== Change to your required taxonomy */ ) {

 if ( empty( $args['walker'] ) || is_a( $args['walker'], 'Walker' ) ) { // Don't override 3rd party walkers.
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WPSE_Woothemes_Sensei_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist' ) ) {
        /**
         * Custom walker for switching checkbox inputs to radio.
         *
         * @see Walker_Category_Checklist
         */
        class WPSE_Woothemes_Sensei_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist extends Walker_Category_Checklist {
            public $count = 0;
            function walk( $elements, $max_depth, $args = array() ) {
                $output = parent::walk( $elements, $max_depth, $args );


                if($args['taxonomy'] !== 'lesson-category') {

                    $output = str_replace(
                        array( 'type="checkbox"', "type='checkbox'" ),
                        array( 'type="radio"', "type='radio'" ),
                        $output
                    );

                    if( $this->count == 1 ) { ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                                var radio = jQuery("div#course-category-all li.popular-category:first").find('input');
                                radio.attr('checked','checked');
                            });
                        </script>


                    <?php }


                } else {
                    $output = str_replace(
                        array( 'type="radio"', "type='radio'" ),
                        array( 'type="checkbox"', "type='checkbox'" ),
                        $output
                    );
                   echo ' <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                            jQuery("ul#lesson-categorychecklist li:last").remove();
                            var checkboxes = jQuery("ul#lesson-categorychecklist li").find("input");
                            var checked = false;
                            jQuery.each(checkboxes, function(i,v){
                                if( !checked )
                                    checked = jQuery(v).is(":checked");

                                //console.log(checked);
                            });

                            if( checked === false ) {
                                jQuery("ul#lesson-categorychecklist li:first").find("input").attr("checked","checked");
                            }

                        });
                    </script>';

                }

                $this->count++;

                return $output;
            }
        }
    }

    $args['walker'] = new WPSE_Woothemes_Sensei_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist;
}
}
return $args;}`
```

Comment: Hola Irene, puedes poner el error que te da?

Comment: Hola, el error que me da es directamente hacer que se caiga la web y no poder acceder, soy un poco desastre y ando aún aprendiendo.

Comment: En la consola web (F12) no te sale nada? en la pantalla ningun codigo de error?

Comment: Y en los logs de PHP? Tampoco? Otra pregunta. Qué significa "el fragmento que me permite hacerlo es comentado". Significa que todo el código que pusiste lo tienes comentado en tu blog?

Comment: El fragmento perteneciente al javascript es el que no permite la ejecución, y es el en el que necesitaría que funcionase. Lo que necesito es marcar más de una checkbox a la vez. Porque es una modificación para unas categorías de wordpress. En F12 no sale ningún código de error

Comment: Un error no hace de las suyas sin dejar rastro!! en algún lado tiene que salir el error, tanto como en la consola o en el network... "directamente hacer que se caiga la web y no poder acceder" tampoco es un error!! tiene que decir por lo menos "error 500" tienes que darnos pistas del error si no nadie te va a poder ayudar

Answer (score -1):

Prueba abriendo y cerrando las llaves {} en la linea siguiente por por que quizas no lo reconozca, sigo sin entender que parte comentada de código te hace la función.

```
if( !checked )
   checked = jQuery(v).is(":checked");
```

Quede asi:

```
if( !checked ) {
   checked = jQuery(v).is(":checked");
}
```

Comment: Hola @Maghdiel. Gracias por tu aporte. No obstante, no hay diferencia entre los dos fragmentos que estás presentando. Si bien es recomendable utilizar siempre llaves, no son necesarias en este caso.